# Created smart home activity (google home) with OAuth2 (which works) but can't Link it in the "Home" app

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-home, google-smart-home

**Introduction**

I've been trying to build a Google Home, Smart Home Activity that integrates with Azure AD. I've been able to correctly sign in so the ClientId/endpoints/scopes must be correct.

When I try to connect to the Smart Home skill using the simulator it shows me an error that this functionality isn't supported in the simulator. So I then moved to my actual android phone. However when I try to link to the smart home service in the google home app it correctly asks me to login, but after logging in the login screen disappears and I'm back to selecting a service I want to link to.

Flow to activate service:

[image: Clicked on this]
[image: Click on my service]
[image: OAuth login redirects back to the app]
[image: After loading for a bit it goes back to the initial screen and no service was linked]

So after the 4th image it just goes back to the original screen and no skill was ever added.

I've also setup NGROK as my fullfillment URL but I see no activity other then some of my own tests:

[image]

**My configuration**

This is the way I've set everything up:

Azure AD:

[image]

I've also configured the direct URL to be: `https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/davysmarthome`

Google Home (Action):

[image]

Google Home (OAuth):

[image]

**Summary**

My question would be why my skill doesn't want to be linked to. I have not yet implemented anything in my actual API yet but I would expect NGROK to at least show some data traffic if google home would actually try to link itself and request what devices are connected.

Comment: Curious if you tried Azure AD B2C as described in this example: https://github.com/Dayzure/AzureADB2CwithGoogleSmartHome/blob/master/readme.md ?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the 4th image, it can be seen that you haven't enabled "Testing" on your project, sometimes the Account Linking process fails if testing has been disabled for any reason. To make sure testing is enabled for the project, go to AoG Console > Develop > Account Linking > Test (Upper Right Corner).
But, in this case, it does not necessarily mean that the account linking failed, it is also possible that account linking succeeded, but failed in SmartHome Sync. To make sure if account linking has succeeded, please visit https://myaccount.google.com/accountlinking?hl=en and check if the account has been linked correctly.

There are other tools available that can help you with debugging OAuth issues such as "OAuth Playground". It helps in finding out the exact issue causing the error.